# Read file line by line and execute those lines in Haskell

Tags: haskell

i want to read from a file (contains haskell commands per line). I want to read line by line and execute those and display the result

my following code is not working... print is not processing the command, it is just displaying it:

```
import System.IO
import Control.Monad

main = do
  fileContents <- readFile "Instructions.txt"
  mapM_ f (lines fileContents)

f line = do
    putStrLn ("Processing Instruction:" ++ line)
    print line
```

instruction file contains haskell commands.

Comment: You need to re-implement `ghci`, right?

Comment: yes i want to execute it back on ghci

Comment: Let me try again. The program you are trying to write is supposed to do essentially the same thing `ghci` does. Namely, read Haskell expressions from the standard input and evaluate them. Is that correct?

Comment: alternatively you can `runhaskell Instructions.hs`, assuming it is a valid Haskell program

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty simple: change `print` in `f` to a function which will interpret the line and execute it.

Iit is very easy to use `system` from `System.Cmd` and run commands via `ghc - e`. Your code then becomes

```
import System.IO
import System.Cmd
import Control.Monad

main = do
  fileContents <- readFile "Instructions.txt"
  mapM_ f (lines fileContents)

f line = do
  putStrLn ("Processing Instruction:" ++ line)
  system $ "ghc -e " ++ show line
```

You still need to add error checking and stuff like that but I'll leave those parts to you since they are not central to the question.

Comment: I mean which function should I use there to do that... I searched books, internet but could not find suitable answer... please help

Comment: See now. I guess that's what you want. If not, please provide an example of input file and the output that you need to obtain.

Comment: sorry I should be clear in my question. sample instruction file contains haskell commands:->[x*2 | x <- [1..10]]
sum [1,2,3,4,5]
product [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: system command is working perfectly fine with command line commands but this is not processing haskell commands

Comment: I don't think you need to write a function to do that. Looks pretty hard for a homework.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for unsafeEval

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/plugins/1.5.1.3/doc/html/System-Eval-Haskell.html

But this is almost certainly definitely always a very bad idea for any real program, and not only goes against every guideline and rule of programming but also the fundamental principles of haskell programming.

If you just want something to read a file line by line and output the result, **ghc** already does this for you pretty well.

`ghc -e "command"` will execute the command and output to stdout, so it would be pretty easy to write a simple bash script to do this for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
# linebyline.sh

while read line; do
    ghc -e "$line"
done
```

which you can run by:

```
cat myfile.txt | linebyline.sh
```

or you don't even need a separate script:

```
cat myfile.txt | while read line; do ghc -e "$line"; done
```